# How to I save grep regex matched result to a variable?

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I have a variable : `email="yask123@gmail.com"` and I want to get its username portion to be stored in another variable.

I used the following `grep` command:

```
$ $email | grep '.*@'
```

Which gave me following output.

`yask123@`gmail.com

I want to save the matched string in a variable.

I tried

```
res=`echo $email | grep '.*@'`
```

which didn't work.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  What does echo $email | grep '.*@' return for you?

Comment: It returns this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q149y6igk1agej/Screenshot%202016-01-20%2001.38.27.png?dl=0&preview=Screenshot+2016-01-20+01.38.27.png 

I wish to store the matched string in another variable.

Comment: `$email | grep ...` means "run the **command** which is stored in the `$email` variable, and pipe it to `grep`.   `echo $email | grep ...` means pass the **contents** of the `$email` variable through `grep`.  Not the same.

Comment: If I run `$email | grep ...` where `email` contains `yask123@gmail.com`, I get `yask123@gmail.com: command not found`.  That is output by the shell, not grep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
email="yask123@gmail.com"
echo "${email%@*}"
```

Output:

```
yask123
```

See: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32)

Comment: Wow, thats brilliant! :D

Comment: But still I was curious, is there No way to store the result of matched string using `grep` ?

Comment: With GNU grep: `res=$(echo $email | grep -Po '.*(?=@)')`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to do something more complex than shell match, which is absolutely valid applied to your example:

```
res=$(echo $email | sed 's/\(.*\)@.*/\1/')
```

Comment: or `res=$(echo $email | sed 's/@.*//')`